# how can we use multiple value using for each loop

Tags: php

This is my code. I want to print mobile no and attendance but there is a problem when I'm printing attendance value its not properly inserted.
If I run this code then attendance of student is coming wrong, if all are selected then it marks all present, but any student is absent and if I do not marked it then it gives wrong output.

```
$att     = $_POST['att'];
$bsubmit = $_POST['mobileno1'];
$rollno  = $_POST['mobileno1'];
$e       = A;

foreach ($att as $index => $value) {
    if ($att[$index] == "P") {
        $query  = "INSERT INTO Attendances(mobileNo,AttendanceStatus) VALUES(' " . $bsubmit[$index] . " ',' " . $att[$index] . " ' )";
        $result = $conna->query($query);
        echo($att[$index]);
        echo($bsubmit[$index]);
    }
    if ($att[$index] == "A") {
        $query  = "INSERT INTO Attendances(mobileNo,AttendanceStatus) VALUES(' " . $bsubmit[$index] . " ',' " . $e . " ' )";
        $result = $conna->query($query);
        echo($att[$index]);
        echo($bsubmit[$index]);
    }
```

html form is :

```
<form action="attendinsert.php" method="post">
    <table id="attendance" width="567" border="1 bold">
        <tr>
            <th width="83" scope="col">ID</th>
            <th width="83" scope="col">Student Name</th>
            <th width="55" scope="col">Student Roll.No</th>
            <th width="51" scope="col">Attendance</th>
        </tr>

        <?php while (list($id, $name, $mobileno) = $report->fetch_row()) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $id ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $name ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mobileno ?></td>
                <td align="center">
                    <?php echo '<input type="checkbox"   name="att[]" value="P"   />'; ?>
                </td>
                <input type="hidden" name="mobileno1[]" value="<?php echo
                $mobileno; ?>"/>

            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        echo '</table>';
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="submit">
        </input>
</form>
```

Comment: `$e=A;` what's this? If you intend to insert the letter A, it needs to be a string - then it should have quotes around it, `$e = 'A';` (without it, it's interpreted as a constant)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it in order to get an (useful) answer. For example, *"there is a problem"* doesn't help finding the problem. Of course there is a problem if you are here asking for help but how do you know that? What is the actual behaviour and what is the expected behaviour of the posted code?

Comment: Also, when facing errors, enable error-reporting - both for PHP and MySQL (add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top of your file, and get the error thrown back from MySQL (we don't know what API you're using, so you need to be more specific there).

Comment: @Qirel while your statement regarding constants is correct, it is probably not the cause of the problem. When PHP reaches a constant it doesn't know it assumes the programmer's intention was to write a string. Accordingly, if the constant `A` is not defined, the statement `$e = A;` is identical with `$e = 'A';`

Comment: @Qirel   problem is that in the array of att(attendance) value is not coming in order if i checked all value then it will be ok but if i check only one then it creates problem. sometime it mark present all students some time answer is opposite what i need.

Comment: @AtulKumar Can you provide the HTML form? Sounds like you just need to specifically name the indexes in your form.

Comment: Why do you use PHP to echo a static string in that form?

Comment: @Qirel html form is above

Comment: @Pharaoh because to print the information of every student

Comment: But you echo the identical string `<input type="checkbox"   name="att[]" value="P"   />` each time. You could remove the `<?php echo ?>` wrapper and just insert it as HTML code.